# How can I read numbers from an file and use them in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am making a program that asked the user to open and existing txt file. The program should read the numbers from the file and storing them into arrays. I am supposed to create different functions with those numbers in the array, such as getting the largest number, the lowest number, the sum, and the average. I have done the functions already but I do not know how to extract the numbers from the array.

Here is an example of numbers but instead of being separated by space, they're separated by a new line.

53
22
87
103
-3
75
220
1
64
543
98
44

```
int getLowest(int num[], int size);
int getHighest(int num[], int size);
int getSum(int num[], int size);
int getAverage(int num[], int size);

int main()
{
    string fileName;
    ifstream inputFile;
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];

    cout << "Enter the name of imput file: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if (inputFile)
    {

            cout << " numbers read from input file.\n"
                << "The lowest value is " << getLowest(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Display error message
        cout << "Error, this file does not exist.";
    }
    system("pause");
}

int getLowest(int num[], int size)
{
    int temp = num[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {        
        if (temp < num[i]) 
        {                 
            temp = num[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

int getHighest(int num[], int size)
{
    int temp = num[0];

    for (int i = 0; i > size; i++)
    {
        if (temp > num[i])
        {
            temp = num[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

int getSum(int num[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += num[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

double getAverage(int num[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += num[i];
    }

    average = sum / size;

    return average;
}
```

When I open the file with the numbers shown above, the result I get does not work. I get:

010FFCE0 numbers read from input file.
The lowest value is 1968178332

Where it says "010FFCE0" i would like to get something that says the numbers of values, and the lowest value I would like it to be the actual lowest value.

Comment: FYI, getAverage() is simply `return getSum(num, size) / (double)size;`.  One thing you should be aware of is to reuse the code you already wrote.

Comment: Also, you are calling `getLowest` before you read anything from the file.  Programs run top-down, a line at a time.  Seems as if you should review how to read data from a file.  All you did was open the file.

Comment: A key to [debugging programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is to make sure each step works. Before worrying about the highest/lowest/etc. functions, you should verify that you have in fact "read the numbers from the file and storing them into arrays". Have you done that yet?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am aware of that. I have fixed that in another IDE I am using. Also How do I read the data from the file. That is my question. Thank you.

Comment: If you have trouble with a basic fundamental of the language such as reading data from a file, you should write a very simple 3 to 5 line program doing or attempting to do just that -- read from a file.  All of these things with average and sums are not important.  Also all C++ books discuss how to read from a file Hint -- you're reading from a file already in your program -- `cin >> fileName` reads from a "file", that file being the keyboard.  Reading from a file uses the exact same syntax, using `>>`.

Comment: @JaMiT Well, that is what I am struggling with, I am not sure how to do that. I am a beginner and kind of have issues with files and arrays so using both is kind of my issue.

Comment: @LLC You should ask about what you are struggling with, not about the next steps you plan to take. Otherwise your question will likely be unclear and the answers likely unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of reading numbers from a file into `std::vector<int>`:

```
int number = 0;
std::vector<int>    database;
while (inputFile >> number)
{
  database.push_back(number);
}
```

The `std::vector` is a good choice here because it expands dynamically as necessary (performing dynamic memory allocation as necessary).

However, you don't need to store the numbers in order to determine the highest, lowest and average:

```
int sum = 0;
int highest;
int lowest;
inputFile >> highest;
lowest = highest;
sum = highest;
int number;
int quantity = 1;
while (inputFile >> number)
{
  if (number > highest)
  {
    highest = number;
  }
  if (number < lowest)
  {
    lowest = number;
  }
  sum += number;
  ++quantity;
}
double average = (sum * 1.0) / quantity;
```